# Regex capture two groups in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to get two substrings 2 and 1 in the example (the home and away team result) from the following string: 'Final result 2:1 (1:1, 1:0)'. Of course I can use split() or similar but I've decided to solve this using regex, currently with no luck. Here is what I've tried:

```
var text = "Final result 2:1 (1:1, 1:0)";
var pattern = @"\w+(\d+):(\d+)";
var myRegex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var m = myRegex.Match(text);
```

Unfortunatelly the m.Captures is empty.

What I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I would like to have 1 match with 2 captured groups: "2" and "1"

Comment: You're missing a space between `\w+` and `(\d+)...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your could try the below regex which matches the string in this `number:number` format(*format must be followed by a space*) and also captures the digits before and after `:`  ,

```
(\d+):(\d+)(?= )
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cA4wE0/11)

Comment: The demo works cool, thx I just can not find how to access the match's two capturing groups in C#. It seems there is one capture: "2:1"...

Comment: see this ideone link http://ideone.com/X4h4nW

Comment: May I ask why the lookahead (?= ) is necessary? It seems working without it also... Thx

Answer (score 1):

Your regex almost works, you need to tweak it a little. You can use this regex instead:

```
[\w\s]+(\d+):(\d+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/aA1hY3/1)**

[image]